TracingInstrumentation for micro frontends using Grafana Faro
I have a micro frontend application that I have been monitoring using Grafana Faro. I have initialized one Faro instance per micro frontend and set the isolate variable to true in all of them, except for the one that has my global scope. I have also initialized the TracingInstrumentation in all of them. The problem is that traces that come from different micro frontends are considered to come from the same mfe, at least that is what is show to me in Grafana Cloud. For example, I have an mfe called A that sends a request to http://localhost:8000/ and a micro frontend called B that sends a request to http://localhost:8000/b. A never sends a request to http://localhost:8000/b, but, when the request is sent to that url, what appears in Grafana Cloud is as if the request had been sent by A.
I have tried to change propagateTraceHeaderCorsUrls inside the initialization of the TracingInstrumentation, but that does not seem to be the problem. When I did that, all that happened was that the backend traces were not integrated with the frontend traces anymore. The request trace made by the frontend was still there, and still had the wrong service's name attached to it.
Is there a way for me to solve this? I am not quite sure what I have done wrong.
